# Centering a UIView with several subviews after rotation

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, centering, autosize

In a view are a UIScrollview & UIView. The 2nd has 5 subviews (2 hidden).

I want to keep the layout of the 5 subviews (As of, time/date, Refresh & hiddens) AND center the UIView after rotation using IB's View Inspector. So far, none of the combinations I've used has worked. The UIView is not connected to the controller (as an instance variable). Its 5 subviews are.

How to accomplish this? (Listing what I've tried could fill a book.)

Labels, Soon to be gone and above are in the scroll view and are resizing correctly.

The closet I got to the desired result was 'dashing' all the lines. That led to a centered 320px UIView with the scroll view's contents exposed on either side in landscape.

Portrait with View Inspector settings:

[image: Portrait with View Inspector settings]

Landscape with settings:

[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are steps to keep the bottom UIView's items center aligned and spacing constant.

1. Undo the left & right (autosizing) 'struts' for all the subviews. (Mine only had the top strut ON after modification & no springs on)
2. In the UIView's (containing subviews) Size Inspector, Show > Layout Rectangle and change X to -90.
3. Now change the Width to 480. Entering this may cause the elements to 'spread out' left & right to fill the 480. Some of the subviews may disappear.
4. Reposition the subviews back to the desired position. This might take selecting one in the  Document Outline, cutting and pasting it back into view.
5. Optionally Clean the project.
6. Build & Run

The improved version with lower UIView (centered and same spacing) & it's settings displayed in Xcode:

[image: lower UIView centered with spacing consistent]

It had to be possible in Interface Builder!!